# sql select where column value exists in a text

Tags: sql, select

I'm looking for reverse of like operator. I have long text and a sql table of words. I want to select words which exist inside the text. Something like this:

```
select word from mytable where word in ('this is a long story')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `CHARINDEX`

```
select word from mytable where CHARINDEX(word , 'this is a long story') > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT word
FROM mytable
WHERE INSTR('this is a long story', word) > 0
```

The function INSTR is multibyte safe, and is case sensitive only if at least one argument is a binary string. Hope it helps.

Comment: This did not work in sql server. I received error that  instr is not a predefined function.

Answer (score 1):

This can be DB depended, for example with postgreSQL you can do something like this:

```
select word from mytable where word  in (select regexp_split_to_table('this is a long story', E'\\s+') );
```

Other databases do have a similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select word from mytable where 'this is a long story' like '%' || word || '%'
```

Do you mean like this?

Comment: didn work. I tried `like concat('%',  word ,'%')` instead.